# Single producer multiple consumer implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading

Consider the following situation

```
 private BlockingCollection<Consumer> consumers { get; set; }


 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) => {

                while (consumers.Count == 0)
                    Thread.Sleep(20);

                Consumer consumer;
                if (consumers.TryTake(out consumer)) {
                    var result = consumer.Read(data);
                    //do stuff with result
                    if (consumers.TryAdd(consumer)) {
                        //ok
                    }
                }
            });
```

Is there a way to avoid this timeout when there isn't a consumer available to process the request?

Comment: If you're using `Thread.Sleep` you're doing something wrong. Why aren't you using a `WaitHandle` to block the thread instead?

Comment: Have you tried `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection` for ex. It has a bounded capacity.

Comment: What is the type of `consumers`?  You need to look into using [semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for allowing the consumer to take X items max and then wait on an event when there is no more items

Comment: @TonyTheLion the consumers are exe files that become unavailable while they do the processing, that's why I remove them from the collection

Comment: @Dai will take a look onto it

Comment: @Eser I'm using a blockingcollection (consumers variable). I could be misusing it tho.

Comment: @Chris Then what about to include it your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) for your consumers collection. It will block on the [Take()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085(v=vs.110).aspx) call when no objects are available and continue as soon as items are available.

EDIT (after OP showed it was already using the BlockingCollection):
Replace the TryTake call with a call to Take which does block until an item is available. And remove the Thread.Sleep call all together.

EDIT: Added code snippet.

```
Consumer consumer = consumers.Take();
var result = consumer.Read(data); //do stuff with result 
if (consumers.TryAdd(consumer)) 
{ 
   //ok 
}
```

Comment: And what is the meaning of saying "use this", when OP already uses it

Comment: @Eser I hadn't noticed the consumers collection declaration. Perhaps added in a later edit?

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea yeah, I added it later on, cause I thought TryTake and TryAdd would be enough to clarify the type :) sorry

Comment: @Eser I'm typing in the Android app and the question is not visible (nor its updates) while typing an answer.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea OK, Ask SO to fix it.

Comment: @Eser True... Even if there's not enough room on a mobile device to display both the question and answer editor, at least a notification letting people know the question has been edited would be nice.

Comment: @Chris BTW: I don't think your desing is correct. I would use `N` consumers with `N` threads and use `BlockingCollection` as a collection of of data to be consumed. Producer would put the data and any one of the consumers would get the data from  `BlockingCollection` and do the job.

Comment: @Eser that's right but i'm not completely aware how to implement that since the consumers must constantly check whether there's any data available for processing thus there must be an entity which constantly checks is there any data

Comment: @Chris I have to agree with Eser. Further more, the work items should be on the blocking collection, not the consumers themselves. Your implementation is kinda awkward.

Answer (score 5):

This may be a late answer but I would do it this way (assume your *Producer* produces some string data and *Consumers* use them)

```
public class PC
{
    const int THREADS = 5;
    static BlockingCollection<string> _Collection = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    public PC()
    {
        //1 producer  
        Task.Run(()=>Producer());
        //N consumer
        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) Task.Run(() => Consumer());
    }

    void Producer()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); //Not to flood our case...
             //Produce it
            _Collection.Add(rnd.Next().ToString());
        }
    }

    void Consumer()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            string str = _Collection.Take();
            //Consume it
            Console.WriteLine("Thread \"{0}\" consumed {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer, by using the while(true) loop in the consumer don't the threads remain running? Could that cause any problems ? Should I manage their state?

Comment: @Chris The loop will not be a tight one because Take() will block when no elements will be available.

Comment: Is also correct to use foreach with GetConsumingEnumerable() instead of while?